# Are all my ports closed?

Tags: networking, server, mediaserver, plex

I was having trouble getting remote connections to Plex Server to work. Now I have noticed that, using tools such as canyouseeme.org, none of my services can be accessed remotely. I ran "netstat -plnt" and tried the ports assigned to Dropbox and other services - all failed. Any idea what is happening?

P.S. I tested with a direct connection to my machine - no NAT. I did test with a router and NAT too though.

`netstat -plnt` output:

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:51376         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2830/Plex Plug-in [
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:32400           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1677/Plex Media Ser
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:32401         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1677/Plex Media Ser
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52242         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2878/Plex Plug-in [
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:32469           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1853/Plex DLNA Serv
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7003            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4121/skype      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17500           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4239/dropbox    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:17600         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4239/dropbox    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:17603         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4239/dropbox    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1093            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1853/Plex DLNA Serv
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5900            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4117/vino-server
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34732         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1725/Plex Plug-in [
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:51501         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2504/Plex Plug-in [
tcp6       0      0 :::17500                :::*                    LISTEN      4239/dropbox    
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::5800                 :::*                    LISTEN      4117/vino-server
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::5900                 :::*                    LISTEN      4117/vino-server
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a nmap scan (from inside and outside your LAN) and see if you can access the ports your server is listening on are available from outside

```
sudo apt install nmap #to install nmap
nmap -p 32400,32469,7003,17500,445,1093,139,5900 YOUR_SERVERS_IP_ADDRESS
```

then you can list your iptables rules to see if there are ports blocked from your firewall

```
sudo iptables -L
```

if so, you can add your services using ufw ([Documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall)) profiles ([one for Plex media server](https://gist.github.com/schwuk/6376468)) or just specify the ports manually an open them.

Comment: `sudo iptables -L`  doesn't show any ports (all three rules ACCEPT).  `sudo ufw -status` says it's inactive, so I suppose it's not a firewall problem?